# Unable to create dev/rfcomm port

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port

I am have [Bluno nano](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1122.html) and would like to connect it my pc(**Ubuntu 16.06**) and receive information via blue tooth. some online Q&A but unable to make it work.

1. I paired Bluno nano my pc (checked via - `$ bluetoothctl` , [bluetooth]# paired-devices).
2. After that I ran `$ sudo rfcomm bind 0 F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC 1`

but I am unable to see `/dev/rfcomm0` . Do I need to create any config files ?

Connection to blutooth is done by the following commands

```
$ rfkill list all
$ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
$ sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# pairable on
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# scan off
[bluetooth]# connect F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC 
[bluno]# pair F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC 
[bluno]# trust F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC
```

Comment: your method looks is simplest and best that should work. maybe try  `sudo apt install gnome-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` which installs some bluetooth stuff alongside the bluez

Answer (score 3):

This method worked for me.

After you paired to the device and connected connected successfully, discover services that are using rfcomm on the remote device:

```
sdptool browse <remote_dev>
sdptool browse 12:34:56:78:11:22
```

take note of all the possible rfcomm and their channels (remote_channel)

Now create a virtual rfcomm device on our machine:

```
rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 2
```

you can replace 2 with any value. it is our channel

Then bind the remote rfcomm to our virtual rfcomm device:

```
sudo rfcomm bind <virtual_rfcommdev> <remote_mac> <remote_channel>  
sudo rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 12:34:56:78:11:22 2
```

if you prefer a one liner

```
 rfcomm bind 0 12:34:56:78:11:22 1
```

You can check if it is worked by sending it a test AT command

first install picocom:

```
sudo apt install picocom
```

then check if the device is present:

```
ls /dev/rfcomm*
```

then start picocom on the rfcomm:

```
sudo picocom -c /dev/rfcomm0
```

**-c** to make the command visible as you type

you get sometime like

```
picocom v2.2

port is        : /dev/rfcomm0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 9600
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
stopbits are   : 1
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv -E
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,

terminal is ready
```

now type **AT** and press enter. If you get OK then it working.

Comment: I tried
$ sdptool browse F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC
Failed to connect to SDP server on F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC: Host is down

Comment: I also tried directly 
$ sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC 2 
It says "Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down"

Comment: your device probably is be paired but not connected.  inside the bluetoothctl shell do `connect <Bluno mac> ` and repeat the sdptool step again

Comment: When i tried `[Bluno]# connect F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC` It displayed `Connection successful`.  Just to cross check i also tried `[Bluno]# paired-devices ` and it displayed the device too.  I also tried `hciconfig hci0 up` and then sdptool browse step but it displayed the same statement `SDP server on F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC: Host is down`

Comment: Hi , Once connected how can i test with AT commands ?

Comment: i will edit my answer to include that

Comment: Thank you very much . Unfortunately I am still unable to connect rfcomm port.  Not really sure about the problem.  Previously i was able to the pair the device(although SDP server on F4:5E:AB:AA:BB:CC: Host is down).After updating the Bluez software from 5.37 to  5.49, only  connection is established to the device but can't pair.

Comment: how were you able to connect when you were using bluez 5.37?

Comment: Hi,  i also edited the question with the commands.