# How can I listen to insecure bluetooth serial connection in Ubuntu? (with Android phone)

Tags: networking, bluetooth, android

I am trying to listen to an Android phone device and display it in console (basically establish connection and verify that it works).

I am not sure if this is the issue with Ubuntu drivers. Can I request anyone to let me know any possible solutions or even the direction I should be looking for? Any help will be gratefully acknowledged.

**Edit**
As per @vidarlo 's valuable comments, I am adding the following details:
I am trying to run my custom Joypad app that I had built along the lines of github.com/TraQuad/TraQuad-Controller three years ago. It was working beautifully with Windows. I wish to use that android joypad (similar to Arduino BT Joystick free) and run my simulator in Ubuntu. I am not sure if Sony has disabled that profile via system updates. sdptool browse gave the following result: https://pastebin.com/s90jZWis

**Edit 3**

I am able to see /dev/rfcomm0 now after following [Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776806/bluetooth-on-ubuntu-16-04) (maybe, it is also due to some of the other posts I tried). However, when I try [Unable to create dev/rfcomm port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025080/unable-to-create-dev-rfcomm-port) , I get

> sudo picocom -c /dev/rfcomm0 picocom v2.2
>
> port is        : /dev/rfcomm0 flowcontrol    : none baudrate is    :
>   9600 parity is      : none databits are   : 8 stopbits are   : 1
>   escape is      : C-a local echo is  : yes noinit is      : no noreset
>   is     : no nolock is      : no send_cmd is    : sz -vv receive_cmd is
>   : rz -vv -E imap is        :  omap is        :  emap is        :
>   crcrlf,delbs,
>
> Type [C-a] [C-h] to see available commands
>
> Terminal ready
>
> FATAL: term closed

**Edit 4**
It is highly likely that I have used insecure connection as Xperia Dual M2 device is quite old. I was going through Android documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID) and the reference code https://github.com/TraQuad/TraQuad-Controller/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/prasadnr/traquad/ProJoypad.java#L759 I have used 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB . So, the question reduces to **How can I listen to insecure bluetooth serial connection in Ubuntu?**

**Edit 5** I am trying https://askubuntu.com/a/104954/950668 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041129/10978972 But, I am not able to get it working even now.

**Edit 6**
I tried to run `sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 A0:E4:53:D8:91:80` and I got
`Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused` . So, I was going through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52221644/10978972 . But, I did not find `Service Name: Serial Port` after running the command. So, ***is this the problem with Ubuntu or with the Android phone?***

Comment: What do you want to transport over the connection? Bluetooth supports many different profiles, including serial, audio and file transport. `rfcomm0` indicates that you're looking for a serial connection to the phone. Is this correct? Are you sure your phone supports it?

Comment: It is to be noted that [cross posting is discouraged on stack exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/468333)

Comment: @Kulfy I don't think that's relevant here. It's two different questions, and this one is at least somewhat related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Vidarlo, Thank you. Yes. I am looking for serial connection. @Kulfy Thanks for letting me know. I was not sure as to which site this question belongs to and they are mostly two different questions. Vidarlo, Thanks for mentioning that the question is related to Ubuntu. Yes. I was just making sure that the Ubuntu part is correct.

Comment: What do you want to use your serial connection for? I checked with my phone, which is a xperia with android as well, and it does not appear to support that bluetooth profile. You can list accessible profiles with `sdptool browse <baddr>`

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks for the quick response and checking with Xperia. I am trying to run my custom Joypad app that I had built along the lines of github.com/TraQuad/TraQuad-Controller three years ago. It was working beautifully with Windows. I wish to use that android joypad (similar to Arduino BT Joystick free) and run my simulator n Ubuntu. I am not sure if Sony has disabled that profile via system updates.

`sdptool browse` gave the following result: https://pastebin.com/dLiLa1RY

Comment: That changes the question *quite a bit*, as you're trying to connect to a specific thing on the phone. I suggest you include that information in your question - and it renders my comments above void and invalid :)

Comment: @vidarlo Done :) I am not sure as to why your valuable comments would be invalid though. Because, it is actually making me believe few of my suspicions.